# Why is my login form not working

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile, authentication

I am making a one-page web app, which includes a registration, login and search form. Currently, the search and registration features are working, but the login form does not function correctly. The code is as follows:

```
//Login code
if(isset($_POST['Name'])){
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$message= '';   
//Handle errors
if((!$Name) || (!$password)){
    $message = 'Please fill in all the fields';
}else{
    //Secure the data
    $Name = preg_replace("#[0-9a-z]#i", "", $Name);
    $password = sha1($password);
$login_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$Name' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1") or die("Could not check your details");
    $login_count = mysql_num_rows($login_query);
    if($login_count != 0){//If account does exist
        //Get the id
        //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($login_query)){
            //$id = $row['id'];
    //  }
        $logged = 1;
        $message = 'Logged in';
    }else{
        $message = 'Your details are incorrect';
        $logged = 0;
    }
}
}//Big if statement for login
```

I appreciate any advice or suggestions. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify "does not function correctly".

At a first thought, I see you don't use [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) at all. It is also recommended to **not** use mysql_* functions, but [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: You should take  closer look at `preg_replace("#[0-9a-z]#i", "", $Name)`. Or is it correct that e.g. the username `User-Name` will become `-` ?

Comment: Anthony Garcia - I just mean that it does not log you in and  refreshes the page, and I don't use sessions because they are  unnecessary (it is a one page site)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add {} to variables and `` to names in MySQL query

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`='{$Name}' AND `password`='{$password}' LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: For what use? A better advice would be to use prepared statements and correct escaping.